# Duplicate callback outputs

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

So I created this dash project but I keep encountering this `Duplicate callback outputs` error.
This is my `index.py` file.

```
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from app import app
from pages import portfolio, prices
from components import navbar

nav = navbar.Navbar()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    nav, 
    html.Div(id='index', children=[]), 
])

@app.callback(Output('index', 'children', allow_duplicate=True),
            [Input('url', 'pathname')],
            prevent_initial_call=True,
            )

def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/prices':
        return prices.layout
    if pathname == '/portfolio':
        return portfolio.layout
    else:
        return "404 Page Error! Please choose a link"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

And this is my `prices.py`

```
# Import necessary libraries 
from dash import html, dcc, callback, Output, Input
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from index import app
from help.helper_funcs import read_file

# Define the page layout
layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        html.Center(html.H1("Prices")),
        html.Br(),
        html.Hr(),
        dcc.Graph(id='prices-graph', style={'height': '80vh'}),
        dcc.Interval(id='interval-component', interval=15000, n_intervals=0),
        html.Button('Buy', id='buy-button', n_clicks=0),
        html.Textarea(id='buy-text', style={'width': '100%'}),
    ])
])

@app.callback(
    [Output('prices-graph', 'figure')],
    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')],
    allow_duplicate=True
)
def update_graph():
    df = read_file("s3://silver-stage-bucket-test/silver_prices.parquet")
    line = px.line(df.to_pandas(), x='datetime', y='solar_price', color_discrete_sequence=['red'], labels={'solar_price': 'Solar Price'})
    second_line = px.line(df.to_pandas(), x='datetime', y='wind_price', color_discrete_sequence=['blue'], labels={'wind_price': 'Wind Price'})
    line.add_trace(second_line.data[0])
    line.update_layout(yaxis_title='Prices')
    return [line]
```

I've looked accross pages wih the same problem but most people have the same id in their Output in app.callback but I don't have this. I've tried allowing duplicates but none seemed to work for me yet.

Both files use the app.callback. But I think my problem lays within the `index.py` file.
This is the full error

```
In the callback for output(s):
  index.children@b80108fca58ba4aeaa5e8c587a7e4ff4
Output 0 (index.children@b80108fca58ba4aeaa5e8c587a7e4ff4) is already in use.
To resolve this, set `allow_duplicate=True` on
duplicate outputs, or combine the outputs into
one callback function, distinguishing the trigger
by using `dash.callback_context` if necessary.
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

#### EDIT

contents of `app.py`

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(__name__, 
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP], 
                meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width"}],
                suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of `app.py`?

Comment: I added the contents of app.py!

Comment: I can't reproduce it so my guess is the problem is somewhere in `components` or `portfolio`. I recommend commenting stuff out and see if the problem still persist so you can isolate the problem better.

Comment: Thank you for looking into my problem, I'll try what you suggested